# Space between text but not after and before text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following sample text:

```
hello,Good Morning,Nice to meet you,awesome
```

How do I allow allow spaces to be typed only between text and not before or after special characters. For example I do not want to allow spaces before and after a comma?

### Code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#s').bind('keyup blur', function() {
    var selectedInput = jQuery(this);
    selectedInput.val(selectedInput.val().replace(/[\s]/g, ''));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="s" value="hello,Good Morning,Nice to meet you,awesome" />
```

**Final Answer:**

**use:** `(/(,\s)|(\s,)/g, ',')`

```
selectedInput.val( selectedInput.val().replace(/(,\s)|(\s,)/g, ',') );
```

Comment: Correct English is to have a space *after* a comma. Can you explain the purpose of this?

Comment: My head hurts just trying to read this question...

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie "How to allow space between text only and not after and before or to say not before and after comma?" this to me just doesnt make sense in English. Can you understand whats being asked?

Comment: @KyleT: Yes (but my brain hurts and the result is not valid for English). He wants to remove any spaces from around commas (for starters at least).

Comment: @KyleT: Edited to what I believe was meant (although the aim is still invalid for English). :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie ah that makes sense. I thought i was losing my mind for a second there haha thanks.

Comment: Why do this as people type? Users will find that annoying beyond belief. why not just clean up the data after it's been entered?

Comment: I hope you did indeed wrap your code in the `ready` function...

Comment: hey i am implementing my custom search that's why i need this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you are looking for is:

```
(/(,\s)|(\s,)/g, ',')
```

And here is the complete JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#s').bind('keyup blur', function() {
    var selectedInput = jQuery(this);
    selectedInput.val(selectedInput.val().replace(/(,\s)|(\s,)/g, ','));
  });
});
```

With a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnyqsc2y/)

Comment: Finally. Something that works (even if the aim is invalid in English :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  jQuery('#s').bind('keyup blur', function() {
    var selectedInput = jQuery(this);
    selectedInput.val(selectedInput.val().replace(/(,\s)|(\s,)/g, ','));
  });
```

Type in the textbox to activate.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tvjLo733/3/)

It may solve your problem but as TrueBlueAussie has mentioned in the comments this is not conventional english. Take care.

Comment: This allows spaces before commas (which is worse) :)

Comment: no no, i can still insert space after text and before comma.

Comment: @HassanAli Updated. Give it a go, if it doesnt work then I dont think i understand the question properly... Aussie thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: Nice try, but enter `space space space comma` and see what happens :) A regex replace would do the trick for multiple spaces.

Comment: what i want is: only allow space between text. why is it so hard to understand :p

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It never occurred to me to try Regex. Thanks for the help sir. Answer updated but i see an answer has already been accepted :)